# Access PgSQL executables from anywhere

Tags: software-installation, executable, path

I've installed PgSQL 9.1.2 from PostgreSQL repositories and all it's fine except that I can't execute command from every path in my OS. For example suppose that I want to run the command `pg_dump`: for that I need to change from (actual path) to `/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin` and then execute as `./pg_dump` even if I'm root user. I think in make a symlink for each executable under `/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin` in `/bin` but I don't know if this is the best way. Also I think in add this `PATH="/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin:$PATH"` to /.bashrc but didn't know the right way to do this. Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open your .bashrc and add the following lines in the end:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin
export PATH
```

Comment: If it worked then please mark the answer as correct and upvote it.

Comment: How I do that? I can vote beacuse my reputation doesn't allow me at this moment

Comment: click on the up arrow above the "0" which is written just before the answer. If you cannot do it then wait till you get some reputation. Although it is strange that you cannot mark the answer correct for the question you asked. :(
Marking correct answer is important because it saves time of others who come looking for similar problem.